# Не загружается сохранения (изображение) в Unity под Android

Tags: android, windows, unity3d

Я получаю фото с камеры телефона и вставляю его в рамку (UI Image). Если вышел из приложения и зашел заново нужно, что бы картинка сохранилась.
Для сохранения использую Asset Easy Save.

Код для сохранения:

```
    public void OnApplicationQuit()
        {
            im1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("um1");
            for (int i = 0; i < im1.Length; i++)
            {
                ES2.SaveImage(im1[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.texture, 
 "fileDirectory" + i + ".png");
            }
        }
```

Код для загрузки:

```
void Start()
    {
        fileDirectory = Application.persistentDataPath;

        if (Directory.Exists("fileDirectory"))
        {
            im1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("um1");

            for (int i = 0; i < im1.Length; i++) {
                Texture2D tyuio = ES2.LoadImage("fileDirectory" + i + ".png");
                Sprite imga = SpriteFromTex2D(tyuio);
                im1[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = imga;
            }
        }
```

Под Windows все работает, а под Android нет, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в пути  fileDirectory = Application.persistentDataPath;
 , в андроиде он другой. Вы дебажили в андроиде?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена, когда решил посмотреть как все таки работает метод OnApplicationQuit(). Раньше думал, что он должен вызываться автоматически, при закрытии приложения, однако в Unity работает немного иначе. Проблема была в том, что в Windows он вызывался автоматически, а в Android ну никак не хотел. Пришлось создать отдельно кнопку и повесить на нее OnApplicationQuit(). После этого все заработало.